# Stuck at building Sony flashtool using source from github (unable to find winjre.zip)

Tags: java, ant, github, sony

I am using Sony Xperia L, so was trying to test flashing stock rom without unblocking bootloader.

Thus, Flashtool was needed whose source is present at this link:https://github.com/Androxyde/Flashtool

I opened the project in Eclipse and started building the project using Ant in order 
`-> build.xml`
`-> deploy-release.xml`

But when I tried to build the third file `setup-windows.xml` it throwed an error unable to find winjre.zip

I checked the code of setup-window.xml and found that winjre.zip was supposed to be in ./jre folder but instead I found .gitignore file.

I am noob so I don't get what is happening. Please help me with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `setup-windows.xml`.

Change `<target name="binaries" depends="clean, main_lib, JRE">`

to`<target name="binaries" depends="clean, main_lib">`

Androxyde has removed the winjre and linuxjre from his repo, so you need a Java environment on your computer.

This tool is not a stock version from Sony.